# SQL Statement alter index and add partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an index in which I have to remove one column and reindex back for rebuild:

```
ALTER INDEX <index_name> REBUILD;
```

Is it possible to add partition when I rebuild an index.  Partition will be based on one of the column index which is a datetime field. Something like:

```
ALTER INDEX <index_name> REBUILD, PARTITION BY RANGE(COLLECTIONTIME) INTERVAL (INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)
(PARTITION INITIAL_PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2014-10-10') );
```

Not sure how to write the sql statement for it. Anyone can help?

Also, if it is possible will the existing records will also be partitioned?

Edit: Database is Oracle

Comment: this is likely better for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do also specify which DBMS, since the ANSI/ISO SQL spec doesn't even mention indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a column from an index which is on a partitioned table I assume the table is huge. This means the index rebuild takes time. You can either do an online rebuild or just create a new index and drop the old one afterwards.

If your index inherits the partition key column you can create a LOCAL, PREFIXED index on the table.

LOCAL means, each index partition has only records from one table partition -- table and index have the same partition structure

PREFIXED means, that the index inherits the partition key and supports partition pruning when the index is read.

The following command will create an index as mentioned above. The partitions are stored in the default tablespace of the user. The partition structure will be the same as the table.

```
create index <index_name> on (<columns>) LOCAL;
```

If you want the partitions to be stored in a different tablespace you can use this command:

```
create index <index_name> on (<columns>) LOCAL
 (partition <index_name>_p1 tablespace whatever_1,
  partition <index_name>_p2 tablespace whatever_2
 );
```